# Bounty: accepted answer but no +250 reputation: am I missing something?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

In this question:

[How to activate mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628907/how-to-activate-mod-rewrite/8861104#8861104)

My answer has been checked, but there's no trace of:

> This question has an open bounty worth +250 reputation from Woho87
>   ending in 4 days.
>
> The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed
>   canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.

... on my reputation.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accepting an answer and awarding a bounty are separate actions.

The OP decided to accept the answer, but kept the bounty open. You can tell because it says that - "This question has an **open** bounty worth +250 reputation from Woho87 ending in 4 days."

Once the OP decides to award the bounty (or it gets awarded automatically), the answer that got awarded will show how much it was awarded, just under the vote buttons.

See the FAQ question - [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).